# jupyter notebook not finding python module that is definitely installed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a Python script in Jupyter Notebook that has some module dependencies.

Here is where I'm importing them:

```
import requests
import furl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
```

When I run that code block in Jupyter, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-9114a07a03b4> in <module>()
      1 import requests
----> 2 import furl
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import json

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'furl'
```

I have both Python 2.7 and 3.7 on my machine.  I have run both py -3 -m pip install furl and py -2 -m pip install furl to successfully install furl on both versions.

Yet, I still get this module not found error.

I have no idea what to do next.  Would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Are you running in virtual environments?

Comment: No, I'm not in any virtual environments.

Comment: If you are running Ubuntu you can try sudo apt-get install python.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed Anaconda also, so I needed to open Anaconda Prompt and run conda install furl.